# Generating documentation in grails 4.0.11 returns a ClassNotFoundException: groovy.text.Template

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy, documentation, grails-plugin

My Setup:
a fresh grails project with **src/docs/fr/guide/test1.gdoc**
content in **test1.gdoc** is:

```
h1. Mon test
h2. Chapitre 1
test a voir
```

as for other, environment setup is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-07-02 12:16:43 UTC
Revision:     774525a055494e0ece39f522ac7ad17498ce032c

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.12 (Azul Systems, Inc. 11.0.12+7-LTS)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-80-generic amd64

| Grails Version: 4.0.11
| JVM Version: 11.0.12
```

why the command (summary) `./gradlew docs` returns a

```
Execution failed for task ':docs'.
> groovy/text/Template
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.text.Template?
```

Comment: Just to make sure: do you have this in your build.gradle? `apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-doc"`

Comment: We ship Grails 4.0.11 configured with Gradle 5.6.4 by default.  Do you get the same error if you use that version of Gradle?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: funny though when I remove the file test1.gdoc it compiles fine (though with no other gdoc files in the docs dir)

Comment: could be a hint : https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10795

Comment: or this one: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/issues/107